# Django aggregate filters

Tags: python, django

I have 3 models similar to the below, and I am trying to get the latest sale date for my items in a single query, which is definitely possible using SQL, but I am trying to use the built in Django functionality:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    ...

class InventoryEntry(models.Model):
    delta = models.IntegerField()
    item = models.ForeignKey("Item")
    receipt = models.ForeignKey("Receipt", null=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    ...

class Receipt(models.Model):
    amt = models.IntegerField()
    ...
```

What I am trying to do is query my items and annotate the last time a sale was made on them. The InventoryEntry model can be queried for whether or not an entry was a sale based on the existence of a receipt (inventory can also be adjusted because of an order, or being stolen, etc, and I am only interested in the most recent sale).

My query right now looks something like this, which currently just gets the latest of ANY inventory entry. I want to filter the annotation to only return the max value of created when receipt__isnull=False on the InventoryEntry:

```
Item.objects.filter(**item_qs_kwargs).annotate(latest_sale_date=Max('inventoryentry_set__created'))
```

I attempted to use the When query expression but it did not work as intended, so perhaps I misused it. Any insight would be appreciated

Comment: I have a workaround using the RawSQL object, but I would rather not have my own SQL in there if I can help it.

Comment: you haven't actually posted your attempt at using When

Comment: I don't think its worth posting since how it was not working as intended. I am  hoping someone knows how to get what my question is asking for, me posting what doesn't work won't help much. If you have an idea I owuld be happy to try it and post the results.

Comment: `filter(inventoryentry__receipt__isnull=False)` right after `filter(**item_qs_kwargs)` doesn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution with [conditional expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/conditional-expressions/) should work like this:

```
from django.db.models import Max, Case, When, F

sale_date = Case(When(
    inventoryentry__receipt=None,
    then=None
), default=F('inventoryentry__created'))
qs = Item.objects.annotate(latest_sale_date=Max(sale_date))
```

Comment: I'll give it a try and let you know

Comment: Great answer. Just a quick note: it works the same without the `F` expression. That is: `default='inventoryentry__created'`. Please correct me if I am missing something.

Comment: This seems to work as I asked for it! Thanks! I will point out that its not very performant(try running .query on this, its not ideal!) and the rawsql query I am using, although I figured Django could reproduce it easily and it cannot, is drastically better. I will probably stick with the performant one for now and keep this in my pocket for another time.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried some modified solution. Have a look.

```
from django.db.models import F

Item.objects\
.annotate(latest_inventoryentry_id=Max('inventoryentry__created'))\
.filter(
inventoryentry__id=F('latest_inventoryentry_id'), 
inventoryentry__receipt=None
)
```

I did not check manually. you can check and let me know.

Thanks